# html2canvas function reloading all images on webpage

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html2canvas

When I run html2canvas function it works fine, but it starts loading all images on the current webpage which takes too much time. Is it normal? or am I doing something wrong? Here is the code. There are just 2 images in tag1Div element which I am converting to image. But for some reason in the server log almost all images displayed on the current webpage are being loaded again.

```
    function genTag1(){
        document.getElementById('loaderMsg').innerHTML='<img src="/assets/spinner.gif"> Generating Tag 1 Image...';
        html2canvas($('#tag1Div'), {
                    onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    }
                });

    }
```

Ok I just realized by logging html2canvas process in log that for generating image html2canvas clones the entire document. This is why all assets and images are reloaded again. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Damn... I'm still having this problem today in 2020.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. So far the only way I could stop all images from loading is by "display:none" all unwanted images before calling html2canvas function.

Still hoping for a better solution though.